# Sublime Text: embedding Lua code in html with highlighting

Tags: html, lua, sublimetext

I'd like to embed Lua code in html by putting it between tags  while having SUblime Text's syntax highlight and autocomplete for both languages, the way it automatically does with html/PHP. Is it possible?

Something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>Test</title></head>
    <body>
        <? local n = 3 ?>
        <h1>Test number <? print(n) ?></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's certainly possible, but you'll have to edit the grammar files.

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain how?

Comment: See e.g. https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/syntax.html. I'd recommend grabbing Lua and HTML grammar files, and then figuring out how to "include" Lua in HTML; the [including other files](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/syntax.html#including-other-files) basically already has the example you want (albeit with JS `<script>` rather than Lua).